# Postgresql and connections

Tags: database-connection, connection-pooling, web2py

I am using web2py which creates a connection pool and retains it till something else knocks them off. When conducting performance tests I can see the PostgreSQL connection going up and once the test is over, immediately dropping to 1 or 2. Since the pool_size is set at 10 on web2py, why would this be happening? It has to be something on PostgreSQL server. which setting?

Comment: Unless you can post some server log entries showing PostgreSQL closing the connections from its end, it seems unlikely.

Comment: Now there is no problem. May be the web2py config file was not reloaded after I set the pool size. So the default size of 0 was being used.

Comment: I think you can answer your own questions - probably worth writing that up as an answer and accepting it.